# Error with ExecuteSQL in Phonegap / Android

Tags: android, database, html, sqlite, cordova

**Update I found the solution :**
Ok , I'm just so stupid.... The solution is very easy, I just added the size at line

```
db = window.openDatabase("parking", "1.0", "DB Parking");
```

Now I have

`db = window.openDatabase("parking", "1.0", "DB Parking",40000);`

Now my code is running correctly on my Sensation ICS.

**Hello**,

I'm a french developper of mobile application. I have been using phonegap, to develop Android application, since 1 month. In my application I use Database storage , and I have a problem with the executeSql method.

With my device (HTC Sensation) in Gingerbread (Android 2.3) this code is running correctly:

```
var db;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
       createDB();
}
function createDB() {  
        db = window.openDatabase("parking", "1.0", "DB Parking");
        db.transaction(verifDB, dbEmpty,dbNotEmpty);
}
function verifDB(tx)
{
        try
        {
           tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM ETABLISSEMENT", [], dbNotEmpty, dbEmpty);
        }
        catch(err)
        {
           alert(err);
        }

 }
 function dbEmpty(tx)
 {
       db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
 }
 function dbNotEmpty()
 {
      //Do nothing
 }
```

But yesterday I've upgraded my device in Ice Cream Sandwich (ICS) and today my application is crashing at the line:

```
tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM ETABLISSEMENT", [], dbNotEmpty, dbEmpty);
```

I looked in LogCat tab in Eclipse and I have seen this:

```
02-15 11:00:51.843: E/AndroidRuntime(8030): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 11:00:51.843: E/AndroidRuntime(8030): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-15 11:00:51.843: E/AndroidRuntime(8030):     at com.phonegap.Storage.executeSql(Storage.java:168)
02-15 11:00:51.843: E/AndroidRuntime(8030):     at com.phonegap.Storage.execute(Storage.java:87)
02-15 11:00:51.843: E/AndroidRuntime(8030):     at com.phonegap.api.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:176)
```

I have tried with Phonegap **1.3.0** and **1.4.1** , I use phonegap.jar and phonegap.js who are in Android folder in Phonegap archive.

I hope someone have a solution.

Thank you for reading.
ps: please let me know if you find mistakes in my text thank you.